# Google Maps load sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Maps web app that uses the autocomplete API and v3 maps api and have been

1. Getting navigator geolocation
2. Loading map and page based on that loc or a default loc if not able to get.

I realized this causes a long load time for some people, is it therefore recommended to instead

1. Load a map based on hardcoded values on page load, then
2. make users click to get their geolocation or fill out autocomplete?

Thanks for any suggestions I'm not sure what the best approach/standard practice would be

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your use-cases.

Will you have frequent page loads that will cause users to have to wait constantly? Will you have a high amount of searches through the auto-complete?

If you intend for the auto-complete to be used every time, it does not seem very intuitive for the user to have to click something to get their geolocation and wait for a map load.

If either is the case, having the user wait 1-2 seconds once when they open the site seems less daunting then having to click on something every time they visit your page.

Comment: Ok thanks Tah I'm going to do as you say and get navigator geoloc on load